# Split a large file into smaller files and then integrate them to get the original file

Tags: command-line, bash, files

How do I split a 7GB (movie) file into smaller files of (say) 1GB, and then (in another Ubuntu computer) integrate them to get the original file (using just bash commands)?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To split:

```
split -b 1G -d bigfile bigfile-part
```

To join:

```
cat bigfile-part* > bigfile
```

Comment: +1 best method. I usually like to check that everything worked by running 'md5sum bigfile' before and after.

Comment: it didn't want the -d

Answer (score 25):

To split the file into 1024MBs, using a terminal:

```
split --bytes=1024m original_filename /destination/path/prefix
```

To get the original file:

```
cat /source/path/prefix* > original_filename
```

Comment: this works in Mac OS X High Sierra