# How to split a file up into many smaller files and then reconstruct them?

Tags: scripts, software-recommendation, files, transfer

I need to upload a file which is about a GB to an online server to get to a friend. Now there seems to be a problem with my internet connection because if I try to upload a file more than 20MB then it just stops uploading and won't start again for some reason.

So I would like an application or script(s) (there may be the need for two, one which makes the files, and one which reconstructs them) which can do the following:

- Split the file up into smaller files, where the max size for each file can be set by the user so that this can be used for other cases
- Is able to reconstruct the file at the other end and verify integrity by checking its SHA512SUM

I would prefer it not to compress anything. I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 with GNOME 3.20. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: you did not guess that the command would be "split"? >:) (oh and "cat" to reconnect them)

Comment: @Rinzwind: Ah... Could you please put that as an answer then. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've coded two small scripts that can be used for that. First, put the script (name it 'splitter' or anything you like) in a separate folder with the file to be splitted then in the bash run:

```
./splitter FILE SIZE
```

Being FILE the file to be split and SIZE the size in MB. After that, you will see all the splitted blocks (SPLITTED_FILE.aa, SPLITTED_FILE.ab, and so on...), a checksum file (SPLITTED_CHECK_SHA256SUM) and a tar file with all those files inside (SPLITTED_TAR.tar). Delete all but the tar file. When you need to send it, extract it and send the individual files. Once they arrive, put them again in a tar file with the same name (SPLITTED_TAR.tar) and put it in a separate folder with the second script ('mergefile' or whatever you name it). Run:

```
./mergefile
```

It should extract all the files, merge them in a file with the same name as the original one and check the sha256sum.

Note that **it's a very raw script**, so just use it exactly the way I described, in a separate folder with nothing else in it. That's if you want to use it, think **it's easier to just do it by hand on command line**.. But I wanted to practice some shell script!

splitter script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#Usage: splitter [FILENAME] [SIZE]

PROGRAMNAME=$(basename $0)
PREFIX='SPLITTED_FILE'

if [[ $# != 2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $PROGRAMNAME [FILENAME] [SIZE]"
    exit 1
fi

FILENAME=$1
SIZE=$2

if [[ -f $FILENAME ]]; then
    if [[ $SIZE =~ ^[0-9]+$ && $SIZE != 0 ]]; then
        sha256sum $FILENAME > SPLITTED_CHECK_SHA256SUM
        split -b ${SIZE}'M' $FILENAME $PREFIX
        tar -cf SPLITTED_TAR.tar SPLITTED_FILE* SPLITTED_CHECK_SHA256SUM
        echo "Done."
        exit
    else
        echo "$PROGRAMNAME: Invalid size"
        exit 1
    fi
else
    echo "$PROGRAMNAME: Invalid filename"
    exit 1
fi
```

mergefile script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#Usage: mergefile

PROGRAMNAME=$(basename $0)
PREFIX='SPLITTED_FILE'

if [[ $# != 0 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $PROGRAMNAME. No arguments (SPLITTED_TAR.tar will be merged)"
    exit 1
fi

FILENAME=""

if [[ -f 'SPLITTED_TAR.tar' ]]; then
    tar -xf 'SPLITTED_TAR.tar'
    FILENAME=$(cut -f 3 -d " " SPLITTED_CHECK_SHA256SUM)
    cat ./SPLITTED_FILE* > $FILENAME
    if [[ $(sha256sum $FILENAME | cut -f 3 -d " ") == $(cut -f 3 -d " " SPLITTED_CHECK_SHA256SUM) ]]; then
        echo "SHASUM Checks!"
    else
        echo "File corrupted (SHASUM doesn't check!)"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "Done."
    exit
else
    echo "$PROGRAMNAME: SPLITTED_TAR.tar not found."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: It would be preferable if it used sha512 as opposed to any other lower sha algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the suggested answers before posting.
The first suggested answer is this one:
[Split a large file into smaller files and then integrate them to get the original file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12172/split-a-large-file-into-smaller-files-and-then-integrate-them-to-get-the-origina?rq=1)

And here the commands

```
split -b 20M -d bigfile bigfile-part
cat bigfile-part* > bigfile
```

Edit:

... and for the hashsum part, you can generate a SHA512 checksum file from the original ("big") file:

```
sha512sum bigfile > sha512.txt
```

After putting all the small parts together again, check again with the new file, and compare the values.

Comment: better would be to mark it as a duplicate ;)

Comment: Needs more complication. This is too easy.