# "Error splicing file" while copying from External 3TB drive

Tags: kubuntu, external-hdd, storage

I used Ubuntu and an external 3TB drive. When I try to copy files from the External drive to my Ubuntu machine it says " Error splicing file:input/output error". Please tell me the solution. I have a lot of data on the external hard drive.

Comment: What file system has the partition to where you're copying to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I solve "Error splicing files?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/348888/how-do-i-solve-error-splicing-files)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the destination disk could be formatted with: FAT32 --> Maximum file size = 4GB.

If it was formatted with EXT3, EXT4, or NTFS you could save the file.

But you can also split and join files easily: [Split a large file into smaller files and then integrate them to get the original file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12172/split-a-large-file-into-smaller-files-and-then-integrate-them-to-get-the-original)

Comment: Some of my data are Database back up which is not split.

Comment: Firstly, I would back up the files. Finally, I'd follow the steps detailed in the link that I've shared with you. Why? Because splitting you can transfer your smaller fragments of data to your 3TB drive. Then, joining you can have again your original data, or a copy of it, stored on your 3TB drive.